AAD Authentication .NET Web API via Standalone Angular App using MSAL and OAuth2.0
I'm struggling to authenticate my API using my Web App, I've managed to add a login authentication to access my Web App but I can't get my authentication credentials/token to authenticate API calls. I've temporarily added token in the headers of my API calls in my Web App methods that call the API but this isn't secure.
Every tutorial I've seen uses Modules in angular but I'm using standalone component which means app.modules.ts does not exist. This is my workaround to authenticate my web app but I need help authenticating my web API.
Main.ts (deals with bootstrapping rather than app.modules)
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService,
    MsalRedirectComponent,
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));

msal-config.ts (Config created to provide factories for my main.ts)
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
    return new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
            clientId: environment.uiClientId,
            redirectUri: environment.redirectUrl,
            authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${environment.uitenantId}`,
            postLogoutRedirectUri: '/'
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
        },
            system: {
            allowNativeBroker: false, 
        }
    });
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
    return {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        authRequest: {
            scopes: environment.scope,
        },
    };
}

export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
    const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, string[]>([
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
        ['localhost', ["environment.scope"]],
    ]);

    return {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
        protectedResourceMap,
    };
}

This is my services to calls my API ideally I don't need to add any headers to provide token as my authentication to my web app should deal with this.
API calls (original)
  // getObject(): Observable<Object[]> {
  //   return this.http.get<Object[]>(this.apiUrl).pipe(
  //     catchError(this.handleHttpError)
  //   );
  // }

API calls (with token in headers which I don't want to use)
  getObject(): Observable<Object[]> {
    return this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes: environment.scopeUri }).pipe(
      switchMap(tokenResponse => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`
        });
        return this.http.get<Object[]>(this.apiUrl, { headers }).pipe(
          catchError(this.handleHttpError) // Handle HTTP errors
        );
      }),
      catchError(this.handleTokenError) // Handle token acquisition errors
    );
  }

How can I use MSAL to authenticate my web API via web app for a standalone application?

You have to use withInterceptorsFromDi when trying to implement interceptors using DI.
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptorsFromDi()
    ),
    provideRouter(routes),
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService,
    MsalRedirectComponent,
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));


This fixed everything thank you so much, where did you find this line/where is the source info. I couldn't find anything about this online since most information online aren't using standalone components.
